# Firebase's functions not working on hosted

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

i devlopede an webiste with firebase and also hosted in friebase too, but the problem is , when i open site it throws an error of
`import { initializeApp } from "./firebase/app";`
not found or server 404 .

in short it not getting firebase's functionson hosted site!!
what should i do..?

how to use firebase's functions on hosted site